# XAML Hot reload keeps stopping. What could be the issue?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, hot-reload

I recently started learning xamarin.forms and all was going well suddenly whenever I run an app, the XAML Hot reload will start and then stop. I have restarted my PC several times and even tried creating a new projects but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you enable the Xamarin Hot Reload via check the checkbox at Tools > Options > Xamarin > Hot Reload?

Comment: @Wendy yes I have enabled it but that didn't help. I had to create another emulator before it worked. It's now working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Here's what helped.
- a good internet connection 
- creating another emulator

Answer (score 1):

Factory resetting the emulator also helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you're debugging two apps on your simulator simultaneously , this error would happend.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted visual studio to get XAML hot reload working again.

Tips:

- Wait for VS background tasks to complete "status = ready" before lunching the debugging.
- When debugging is started, watch the below status bar to see "Initializing XAML hot reload" and "XAML hot reload connected" before playing with your XAML

Answer (score 0):

Another case might be you're using an old Xamarin project.
If this is the case - it's worth [changing your Xaml Hot Reload Mode to 'full page mode'][1].

This, along with the 'Apply XAML Hot Reload on document save or via Hot Reload button' (which I'm not sure if had any effect or not) was what did the job for me.

[1]: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#:~:text=From%20Visual%20Studio,Reload%20on%20Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#:%7E:text=From%20Visual%20Studio,Reload%20on%20Mac)).